# what's wrong in mdk(UART//HAL)?

Tags: c, stm32, hal

> USER CODE BEGIN 4**here is right**

```
        int fputc(int ch,FILE *f)
        {
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t *)&ch,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            return ch;
        }
```

> USER CODE BEGIN 4**here is wrong!**

```
        int fgetc(int ch)
        {
            uint8_t ch;
            HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2,(uint8_t *)&ch,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        }
```

[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqPkk.png)

Answer (score 1):

For a start, that definition of `ch` *inside* the function *shadows* the one passed in. In other words, you write to the local copy and then throw it away.

However even if you *didn't* have an explicit local copy, the parameter passed in wouldn't be affected outside this function, because C is pass by value - that means whatever changes to make to `ch` are not reflected back to the caller.

Actually, I'm a little *confused* by your definitions since, in C, `fgetc()` accepts a file pointer and *returns* the character, whereas your function accepts a character that it won't do anything with. So it would probably be more accurate to have:

```
int fgetc(FILE *unused) {
    uint8_t ch8;
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, &ch8, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    return ch8;
}
```

As an aside, there's also a possible problem with your `fputc` call since you cast the address of the `int` into an address of an octet.

That will probably work if you're on a little-endian system since the lower memory address of a multi-octet value is the least significant part. For example, using `'A' (0x41)`

```
Increasing addresses -->
| 0x41 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | <- as four-octet int, little-endian.
| 0x41 |                      <- as one octet.
```

On a big-endian system, that won't work:

```
Increasing addresses -->
| 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x41 | <- as four-octet int, big-endian.
| 0x00 |                      <- as one octet.
```

You can solve that by simply copying the multi-octet value into a single octet, something like:

```
int fputc(int ch, FILE *unused) {
    uint8_t ch8 = ch;
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, &ch8, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    return ch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not input parameter for fgetc and you shold have distinct names for your variables

and you just simple do not  return anything

```
    int fgetc(void)
    {
        uint8_t ch;
        HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2,(uint8_t *)&ch,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        return ch;
    }
```